# Simulate real click python

Tags: python, macros, click

As I can simulate a click as if it were made from the mouse, a game has detection of click events or simulated keys, I would like to know if it is possible to simulate a real click.
Translated.

My code:

```
import time
import keyboard
import pyautogui
from playsound import playsound

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.2
sW, sH = pyautogui.size()
down = False

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('f4'):
        if not down:
            down = True
            playsound('on.mp3')
            pyautogui.moveTo(sW*0.67, sH*0.5)
            pyautogui.click()
            pyautogui.moveTo(sW*0.67, sH*0.6)
            pyautogui.click()
            pyautogui.moveTo(sW*0.67, sH*0.64)
    else:
        down = False
```

Comment: I believe the `mouse` library simulates a real click, just like a macro does, not sure though.  Give it a try.

Comment: It only works outside the game but not in the game.
The anti cheat guide says this:
Ignore injected keyboard inputs (e.g. from AutoHotkey, macro's and on screen keyboard).
So that's why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This code simulates a real click of the mouse.

```
import win32api, win32con
from time import sleep

def click(x,y, duration=30, delay=0.3): 
win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
sleep(duration / 1000)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
sleep(delay)
```

Why?
Because the lib win32api is directly connected with the windows commands.
When u click with the mouse, you actualy triggers a function inside the windows.
win32api does de same.
Also...win32api is the fastest comunication with the windows for this stuff, like image rendering